# Desktop icons not showing when using dolphin

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons, dolphin

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with pretty much the default setup. I decided to install dolphin and use that as my default file browser (via the exo-preferred-applications tool). After I did this, my desktop icons disappeared. I don't really want to go back to nautilus, as dolphin has many features I like much better. How can I get my desktop to show icons? I have Ubuntu tweaks installed and according to that, the home, trash, and device icons should be showing up, but I've got nothing.

Comment: Same problem here with 18.04 LTS